# How to make my function run every hour?

Tags: python, function, web, scraper

With the help of some online tuts (Bucky), I've managed to write a simple web scraper that just checks if some text is on a webpage. What I would like to do however, is have the code run every hour. I assume I will need to host the code also so it does this? I've done some research but can't seem to find a proper way of running it every hour. 
Here is the code I've got so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def odeon_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = "http://www.odeon.co.uk/films/rogue_one_a_star_wars_story/16038/" + str(page) #stores url in variable
        source_code = requests.get(url) #gets url and sets it as source_code variable
        plain_text  = source_code.text #stores plain text in plain_text variable
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml") #create beautifulsoup object
        div_content = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "textComponent"}) #finds all divs with specific class
        for x in div_content:
            find_para = str(x.find('p').text) #finds all paragraphs and stores them in variable
            text_to_search = "Register to be notified" #set text to search to variable
            if text_to_search in find_para: #checks if text is in find_para
                print("No tickets")
            else:
                print("Tickets")
        page += 1


odeon_spider(1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: For Linux machines use `crontab`

Comment: Use cronjobs on Linux, On windows you could use taskscheduler

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be like this:

```
import time

while True:
    call_your_function()
    time.sleep(3600)
```

If you wanna do this on Linux, you can just type

```
nohup python -u your_script_name &
```

and then your script will run as a process.(If you don't kill it, it just keeps running without hangup.)

Comment: I fixed your Python code as there's no `While` but `while` in Python and parenthesis also shouldn't be there. I added `&` to the Linux shell cause otherwise the shell won't get the control back. Ohter than that your code is ok. I would still use cron instead.